# How to get boarding pass during layover?

Tags: lhr, united-airlines, check-in, connecting-flights, aer-lingus

I'm flying from Cork to London with Aer Lingus and then London to Los Angeles with United after an hour layover in London.  United Airlines isn't letting me check in to my flight, saying that my "first flight is with Aer Lingus, check in with them."  So how do I get my boarding pass for my second flight with United?

Answer (score 11):

You'll often get all your boarding passes when you check in to the first flight, so it's likely that Aer Lingus will simply hand it to you.

If the stars aren't aligned and that doesn't happen, just follow the [purple flight connections signs](https://www.britishairways.com/assets/images/information/airport-information/heathrow-flight-connections/760x160-t5-flight-connections-sign-bat5gen51.jpg) when you get to London. You'll reach a transfer desk where you can pick up your boarding pass on your way to your connecting flight.

[image: purple flight connections signs]

The Heathrow website has [a flight connections planner](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections) that will give you a step-by-step guide to your connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I already checked in online with Aer Lingus, and only got my Aer Lingus flight boarding pass.  Should I expect to get my United pass at Cork airport when I check in with Aer Lingus?

Comment: @DevGid When you get to the airport at Cork to hand in your luggage, ask the airline rep at the counter whether they can issue you a boarding pass for the second leg.  If they can't, then you will need to get it at the transfer desk in London.

Comment: @DevGid It's possible. I would ask at the check-in counter if they don't give it to you. I've never flown this route, but there are some [reports online](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/united-airlines-mileageplus/1578859-seats-aer-lingus-flight-ticketed-united.html) from a few years ago of people who needed to get boarding passes issued or reissued by United when they arrived in London, so you very well may need to stop at the transfer desk. The good news is that both airlines are in T2 at Heathrow now, so that will make it easier.